# nil can't be coerced into Float

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm coding a billing system with RoR 3.2.11.

Now I want to calculate the total amount of the bill. For that, I designed the Model like that:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :bill_items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :articles, :through => :bill_items
  attr_accessible :date, :discount, :state, :category, :customer_id, :bill_items_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bill_items, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:count].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

  def total
     bill_items.inject(0) { |acc, bill_items| acc + (bill_items.count * bill_items.article.price) } - discount
  end
end
```

That works great, if something is store in the db. If the "bill_item" is empty, I get the following message:

```
TypeError in Bills# edit
nil can't be coerced into Float
```

It would be great, if anybody can halp me with that problem.

Comment: According to your error the problem is in the `edit` method... Why didn't you include it in your code sample?

Comment: it's not only in the edit view. It's the same at the index page (TypeError in Bills#index). I included the total attribute with "<%= bill.total %>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
I had to cast every attribut to it's type.

Now I've the following line:

```
def total
     bill_items.inject(0) { |acc, bill_items| acc + (bill_items.count.to_i * bill_items.article.price.to_f) } - discount.to_f
end
```

maybe this helps other people, too.

EDIT:
copied wrong code snipped